# Using jodatime in a Mongo entity with Spring Data

Tags: java, jodatime, querydsl, spring-data-mongodb

I have an entity that will be persisted with Spring Data to a Mongo Database:

```
@Document
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @QueryType(PropertyType.DATETIME)
    private DateTime lastUpdate;

}
```

This is my repository:

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends
    MongoRepository<MyEntity, String>,
    QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyEntity> {}
```

And the plugin in my pom.xml for QueryDSL generation

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Still, it's treating DateTime as a regular entity (I've tried with and without QueryType). I'd like it to be treated as date, so I can do comparisons, as right now I cannot:

```
Predicate predicate = QMyEntity.myentity.lastUpdate... // where are the lessThan or greaterThan methods?
```

Of course, if possible, I'd like to stick to JodaTime, instead of falling back to Java Date, or storing the date as millis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.joda.time.DateTime` will normally be treated by Querydsl as a DateTime type, so some extra flag makes Querydsl treat is as an entity type.

That extra flag could be for example that a DateTime typed property is somewhere annotated by `@Embedded` or `@Embeddable`.

If this doesn't solve it then please open a ticket on GitHub for Querydsl.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the latest version of Spring Data MongoDB (1.2.0.RELEASE at the time of writing) the necessary `Converter` implementations for JodaTime types should be registered if you have the library in the classpath (see the [according ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-606)).

If you have to use an older version of it you manually need to write and register these converters as explained in the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/mongo.core.html#mongo.custom-converters).

Comment: I am using the latest version, but I think the issue is with QueryDsl, or at least with MongoAnnotationProcessor not treating DateTime as a datepath.